# Xamarin-iOS Speaker and Microphone Raw Audio Data

Tags: xamarin, audio, xamarin.ios, microphone, speaker

I have a struggle for the last week and a half. My Requirements are as followed:

- Receive PCM16 data over the socket (working)
- Play this data onto the Speaker (byte[] ) (not Working)

also in the other direction i want to:

- Record data from the built in Mic (not working)
- If needed convert to PCM16
- Send the data over socket to the receiver (working)

I got this working really good on android so far. But for iOS i cant find any sample in Xamarin-iOS that is even close to work. Any help would be really apprechiated. I looked at a lot of (xCode) samples on google and SO, but i did not get any of them working/converted.

Comment: Did you use the Nuget plugin?

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT what nuget plugin youre refering to?

Comment: sorry. but what NuGet did you Talk about? I use Visual Studio 19 professional (latest stable) at the moment. But also here: what does a question about "how to do a certain task" depend on my tooling?

Comment: I need relevant code or tools to reproduce your error.